# Difference Between Offline Shipping Carrier vs Online Shipping Carrier

Tags: cart, magento2.2, carrier

I am creating a module for a 3rd party rating for Magento. I only need the rates to show in the cart checkout and there is no label creation, tracking, pickup, etc for this carrier. It will send out an XML request as a post through the **HTTP/ClientFactory** then parse the response to show the rates returned.

My question is, is there a requirement for this to extend **AbstractCarrierOnline**, like **UPS, USPS, and FedEx** do, or can I leave it as extending AbstractCarrier? I currently have it is working as an **AbstractCarrier** but when I've tried to convert it to **AbstractCarrierOnline**, it constructs it just fine but never hits the `collectRates()` method and I don't see any errors anywhere and just says that it is not available. The one main downside I can see is that the Online includes the set and get for CachedQuotes.

Comment: Not sure what I was missing but it is working now. Just completely got the Offline carrier working and copied code over and not the Online carrier works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set shipping module to Online Shipping module, cause You don't need to get (API or etc) rates. Also, your module does not provide a tracking number. It's simply Offline shipping.

> The Magento_OfflineShipping module implements the shipping methods
>   which do not involve a direct interaction with shipping carriers, so
>   called offline shipping methods.

Reference: [MagentoDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/mrg/ce/OfflineShipping.html)